# error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DepartmentContext db = new DepartmentContext();
    var getlist = db.Departments.ToList();
    ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(getlist, "Dept_Id","Dept_Name");
    return View();
}
```

and my Index View is :

```
@model BusinessLayer.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
  <h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.CheckBox("Department", ViewBag.Department as SelectList)
     </div>
 }
  <div>
</div>
```

and i got this error:

```
I am trying to convert web.mvc.selectlist to Iconvertable
```

Please give me a solution

Comment: A `SelectList` is for use in a dropdownlist (a `<select>` element). What are you trying to do here. The `CheckBox()` method is for binding to a `bool` property

Comment: u must use `@Html.ListBox("Department", ViewBag.Department as SelectList)` or `@Html.ListBox("Department",null ,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of checkbox use dropdownlist.

But if you are creating some options allowing user to select departments through checkboxes then use html and populate using loop in your View. MVC has no helpter for creating series of checkboxes that can be attached with datasource like selectList

Comment: provide me with an example